# Changing UITextField Placeholder font

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm changing the placeholder text color with the following code, but when I try to add NSFontAttribute I get the compiler error `"too many arguments to method call, expect 2 have 3"`

```
 UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
        _nameField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Name" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color},@{NSFontAttributeName:@"Roboto-Bold"}];
```

**This Works Fine:**

```
 UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
        _nameField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Name" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

**Objective-C:**

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];    
someUITextField.attributedPlaceholder =
  [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Placeholder Text"
    attributes:@{
       NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
       NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:17.0]
    }
  ];
```

(There are no brackets between literal `dictionary` key-value pairs.)

**Swift:**

```
let attributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 17)! // Note the !
]

someUITextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder Text", attributes:attributes)
```

Comment: NSFontAttributeName expects a UIFont object, not a string. You would need to use something like NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:17.0]

Comment: This changed the color for me but not the font.

Comment: Yeah, in iOS7 the font is not changed.

Comment: When I use this code to change the font size, the positioning of the placeholder within the textfield moves down so it is no longer centered vertically. Any ideas on how to increase the font size of the placeholder text but keep it centered within the textfield?

Answer (score 30):

Update for **Swift 4.x**:

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder Text", attributes: [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
    .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
])
```

Comment: It works well on Xcode 8.3.2 & Swift 3, just a casting of attributes using `as [String : Any]` is required

Answer (score 12):

For the convenience of swift people:

```
someTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "someString", 
attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: PlaceHolderFont])
```

Answer (score 7):

You should subclass UITextField, and override the method of：

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

Here is the implementation below:

```
- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
     NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize]
                             };
    // center vertically
    CGSize textSize = [self.placeholder sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGFloat hdif = rect.size.height - textSize.height;
    hdif = MAX(0, hdif);
    rect.origin.y += ceil(hdif/2.0);
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

For more you can find [click here](http://jansanchez.com/blog/2013/02/24/uitextfield-and-attributedplaceholder/)

Answer (score 5):

Appreciate @ddevaz answer.

### UITextField Subclass solution

Above answer works perfect for `UITextField`. **But when i use `UITextField` subclass and try to execute this method in it. Then its not working.**

I found other solution only when you subclass `UITextField`. Override below method in your `UITextField` subclass and it will do job for you.

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:17.0]
                                     };

    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrDictionary];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Working version for Swift 4**

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                      .font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)]

someTextfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder text", attributes:attributes)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Swift 4**

```
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: .black,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Your font name", size: 14)!
]

someTextfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder text", attributes:attributes)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Swift 4.2 +**

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                  .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]

searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder text",
                                                           attributes: attributes)
```

Reference for more attribute Keys - [NSAttributedString.Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support both iOS 6 and previous versions then:

```
UIColor *placeholderColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
UIFont *placeholderFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

if ([textField respondsToSelector:@selector(attributedPlaceholder)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:textField.placeholder attributes: // NOTE: textField.placeholder can't be nil
              @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor,
                 NSFontAttributeName : placeholderFont }];
#endif
} else { // for pre-iOS6
    [textField setValue:placeholderColor forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    [textField setValue:placeholderFont forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code 
 First find name of system accepted font for your Custom font

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

and then use below code make your placeholder with custom font

```
searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Where are you shopping?" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font }];
```

Else there can be chance to get nil object[1] for font not found

Answer (score 0):

```
    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
 NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 17.0) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0) ]


    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder Text", attributes: attributes)
```

Note: when we use  UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 17.0) method, if the font name can't get it in ios , so it will be nil, so we need to provide the default font. It was explained above.

You can use below code First find name of system accepted font for your Custom font

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:** Placeholder Color change using `UITextField` subclass

```
override func drawPlaceholder(in rect: CGRect) {

        let color = UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 210/255, blue: 210/255, alpha: 1.0)

        if (placeholder?.responds(to: #selector(NSString.draw(in:withAttributes:))))! {

            let fontS = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

            let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color, NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontS] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

            let boundingRect: CGRect = placeholder!.boundingRect(with: rect.size, options: [], attributes: attributes, context: nil)

            placeholder?.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: (rect.size.height / 2) - boundingRect.size.height / 2), withAttributes: attributes)
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem same me. I solve by set Font because some time font can't change when set Font in stroryboard or set in `self.emailTextField.placeholder` .

```
self.emailTextField.font = UIFont(..custom you font....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size of the text and placeholder by simply doing this.

```
field.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
```