# iPhone UITextField - Change placeholder Font and Text Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` where i need to change the `Placeholder` Font and Color, i'm calling the below method in drawRect method,

```
-(void) setFontColorForPlaceHolder
{
    for(id obj in [[self baseScrollView] subviews])
    {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            [obj setAttributedPlaceholder:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[obj placeholder] attributes:@{
                NSFontAttributeName:kFutura_Medium_14 ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]
            }]];
        }
    }
}
```

Here the COLOR is changing but the FONT is not setting. What is the issue here with `setAttributedPlaceholder`.

Comment: There are lots of links available for this try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244790/changing-uitextfield-placeholder-font

Comment: setAttributedPlaceholder Not Working in ios6

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya : Yes absolutely you are right, its working fine in iOS7. So what to do in iOS6.?

Comment: Why are you calling this code from `drawRect:`? That's not appropriate at all.

Comment: @rmaddy So where can i call it??

Comment: Setting the placeholder of a `UITextField` subview isn't part of drawing a custom view. You should set the placeholder once when creating the custom view such as in its `init...` method. A custom view's `drawRect:` should only be used to draw the custom content (if any) of the view. If your custom view only has subview and no custom drawing, you shouldn't even implement the `drawRect:` method.

Answer (score 6):

I was testing in iOS 7.1 and found out that `NSFontAttributeName` isn't doing anything to `UITextField`'s placeholder text.

However, when I changed the font of the UITextField itself, the placeholder text font changed as well:

```
aUITextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:20.0f];
```

Answer (score 2):

### For iOS 6+

```
[textField setValue:your_color forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

To set a font for placeholder, just set a font for textfield before writing textholder.

```
textField.font = your font here;
[textField setValue:your_color forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
textField.placeholder = "your placeholder string here...";
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3 
In your custom class override this:

```
override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
     //set initial attributed placeholder color and font
     self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeholderColor, NSFontAttributeName: placeholderTextFont])
     return bounds
}
```