# How to Resize UITextField Placeholder Text to Fit UITextField width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Can Change UITextField Placeholder Text Color as follows:

```
[txtField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
                    forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Similarly is there any way to Resize UITextField Placeholder Text Font to Fit UITextField width?

Note: I have text fields in custom cell of table view and also using autolayout in custom cell.

Comment: see this https://gist.github.com/jpmhouston/35686fc811b1c62effe5/

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244790/changing-uitextfield-placeholder-font

Comment: thnaks for the links but, i tried it and doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue, here is the solution:

```
UILabel *placeHolderLabel = [self.registrationCodeTextfield valueForKey:@"_placeholderLabel"];
placeHolderLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one coding that i used in ViewDidLoad to set the placeholder of textfield of desirable size.
-----------------------------------code-----------------------------------------

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 20)];
textfieldUsername.leftView = paddingView;
textfieldUsername.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[textfieldUsername setValue:[UIColor lightTextColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

(Nj)

Comment: not working, i want to scale font of textfield placeholder text and i have fixed width textfield which truncates placeholder text@Garry

Comment: @Ronak Chaniyara Did manage to solve this issue? I have exactly same problem.

Please let me know how you solved it!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is code

```
 textField.placeholder = @"Pavankumar";
 [textField setValue:[UIColor greenColor]
                    forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

see below code it change font of the placeholder

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Pavankumar" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-light" size:12.0]}];
```

Comment: i think you have misunderstood the question, i want scale font of textfield placeholder text not color@Pavankumar

Answer (score 0):

You have the placeholder text and you have the frame of the uitextfield . 
From these two you can calculate the font size which fits and assign as a Attributed Placeholder String.

If calculated font size is less than your limit , then use that font size other wise use the limit